# Regex to match uri after mod_rewrite

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a `PHP` `PCRE` regex to match uri's that are rewritted with `Apache`'s `mod_rewrite` module. The uri's are as follow :

```
/param1/param2/param3/param4
```

The rules for the uri

- must contain at least one `/`;
- the params must only allow letters, numbers, `-` and `_`;
- there must be zero or more instances of the first two rules;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
if (preg_match("~^(?:/[\w-]+)+/?$~", $string)) {
    # do stuff
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^(?:/[\w-]+)+/?$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    /                        '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w-]+                   any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), '-' (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  /?                       '/' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reliable :)

Answer (score 2):

```
/\/[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\/]+$/
```

I am assuming that it must start with an `/` and something like this should not match `/param1/param2/param3/param4*`

Comment: It gives me `unknown limiter [`

Comment: `/^(\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{0,}){0,}(\/)?$`

Comment: `preg_match("/\/[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\/]+$/", "/djghdbfjsdhkgfhgk/bdshfbgdfgdfg/abc");`
This works.